# Linking the Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL) with ABAQUS 2019 user-subroutines

Tags: subroutine, lapack, abaqus

I'm currently struggeling with linking / activating the MKL for ABAQUS 2019 user-subroutines. In detail I want to make use of the **LAPACK functions dgetrf, dgetrs and xerbla** in one of my UMAT subroutines.

While compiling, I get the following error message (hope the German version does not bother you):

```
LemaitreDamageModel.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "xerbla" in Funktion "solve_for_inverse".
LemaitreDamageModel.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "dgetrf" in Funktion "solve_for_inverse".
LemaitreDamageModel.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "dgetrs" in Funktion "solve_for_inverse".
```

I then had a look at my Abaqus batch file, which looks like this:

```
@echo off
IF NOT DEFINED abaqus_intel_compiler (
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\ifort\compilers_and_libraries\windows\bin\ifortvars.bat" intel64
  set abaqus_intel_compiler=1
)
"C:\SIMULIA\CAE\2019\win_b64\code\bin\ABQLauncher.exe" %*
```

The called batch file ifortvars.bat holds the following line, which looks like the MKL is already poperly incoorporated in the process:

```
if exist "%BIN_ROOT%..\mkl\bin\mklvars.bat" @call "%BIN_ROOT%..\mkl\bin\mklvars.bat" %C_TARGET_ARCH% %TARGET_VS% %LP64_ILP64%
```

The file mklvar.bat is definetly there. I also tried to do the call via a direct path to the file, but that also didn't helped.
However, what can I do to get rid of the above error message? Obviously, there is still something wrong with the MKL linking.